# multiple threads performing writes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I was hoping someone could advise on how multiple threads can write to a common container (eg a  map). In a scenario where some threads might share the same key using Boost and C++

The  map might be of type : std::map, with different threads accessing the object to modify different data members. Would each thread wait upon hitting unique_lock for the current thread to finish before proceeding?

would it be as simple as each thread entering a critical section as this example:

```
//somewhere within the code
boost::unique_lock mutex;

void modifyMap(const std::string& key,const unsigned int dataX,
               const unsigned int dataY)
{
     // would each thread wait for exclusive access?
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock (mutex);

    // i now have exclusive access no race conditions;
    m_map.find(key)->second.setDataX(dataX);
    m_map.find(key)->second.setDataX(dataY);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is typically *not* a **hash** map, but [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a thread-safe implementation of a data structure. It can be either lock-based (for example implemented by using mutexes) or lock-free (using atomic operations or memory orderings which are supported in C++11 and boost).

I can briefly describe the lock-based approach. For example, you may want to design a thread-safe linked list. If your threads perform only read operations everything is safe. On the other hand if you try to write to this data structure you might need a previous and a next node pointers in the list (if its double-linked you need to update their pointers to point to the inserted node) and while you modify them some other thread might read the incorrect pointer data so you need a lock on the two nodes between which you want to insert your new node. This creates serialization (other threads wait for mutex to be unlocked) and reduces the potential for concurrency.

The full example with a lookup table is available in the book "C++ Concurrency: Practical Multithreading" by Anthony Williams at page 171, listing 6.11. The book itself is a good start for a multithreading programming with the latest C++ standard as the author of the book also designed both boost::thread and C++11 thread libraries.

update: to make your example work for read/write (if you need more operations you need to protect them also) you're better off using boost::shared_mutex which essentially allows multiple-read single write access: if one thread wants to write than it is going acquire an exclusive lock and all other threads will have to wait. Here's some code:

```
template <typename mapType>
class threadSafeMap {

boost::shared_mutex map_mutex;
mapType* m_map;

public:

threadSafeMap() {
    m_map = new mapType();
}


void modifyMap(std::string& key,const unsigned int dataX,
               const unsigned int dataY)
{
    //std::lock_guard in c++11. std::shared_mutex is going to be available in C++14
    //acquire exclusive access - other threads wait
    boost::lock_guard<boost::shared_mutex> lck(map_mutex); 

    m_map.find(key)->second.setDataX(dataX);
    m_map.find(key)->second.setDataX(dataY);
}


int getValueByKey(std::string& key)
{
    //std::lock_guard in c++11. std::shared_mutex is going to be available in C++11
    //acquire shared access - other threads can read. If the other thread needs access it has to wait for a fully unlocked state.
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lck(map_mutex);

    return m_map.getValue(key);
}


~threadSafeMap() {
    delete m_map;
}


};
```

Lock-guard objects are destructed and mutex is unlocked at the end of the lifetime. mapType template can be replaced by your map type.

Comment: thanks for your response, so would my example above work? In short i just want to know whether multiple threads accessing the function above will block until the thread with exclusive access exits (upon which the next thread will proceed modifying the map). This is the behaviour i am looking for

Comment: I added some code. You should use boost::shared_mutex, boost::lock_guard for write and boost::shared_lock for read. Other operations should be modified in the same way if you need them.

Comment: thanks a lot Dmirty, that helped clarify a lot, just one question, would upgrading to unique lock also work?

Comment: If you want to use `std::` or `boost::unique_lock` in the same way as the `std::` or `boost::lock_guard` then you can do the following:

`boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> ulck = boost::unique_lock(map_mutex);
ulck.lock();`
Or you can can make an explicit cast using an explicit constructor - example (3) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock. `unique_lock` just has more flexibility than `lock_guard`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `boost::defer_lock`. Should be:
`boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> ulck = boost::unique_lock(map_mutex, boost::defer_lock);`.

Comment: thanks for the insight, how about boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock (mutex); would that also work?

Comment: @godzilla, `boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock (mutex);` without `boost::defer_lock` throws an exception. I guess this is because there is no constructor defined without explicit locking specification (there are 3 of them according to the ISO standard and boost docs as well as this wiki http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag_t).

Comment: Also if you want to create an object and lock a mutex without calling `mutex.lock();` you can use an explicit constructor `boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> ulck = static_cast<boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex>>(sm);` - it will do the same thing.